Questions about Frankl's book "Man's Search for Meaning"
I read the book and there are three things that I dont understand:

is the book meant to share ideas about philosophic or rather help you find happiness?
does the book claim that happiness isn't important or does it claim that the way to get happiness is by ignoring it?
can "be happy and make others happy" be considered as goal and purpose of life by the book?

I mean for instance if your meaning in life is to help people then you see human suffering as bad thing as an axiom

@TedWrigley I reed it but didn't understand if he says that suffer and happenis are meaning less or the way to achieve them is by focusing on other goals

I read it a while back, but I don't recall the details of his thesis; I'll need to look it over again

I'm in the same situation Ted is. I'll review later.

So after few hours of thinking  , I realised that joy not equal happiness , And suffer is not nessarly means no happiness . For instance assume drinking coffee give you joy is a man that drinks coffee each hour is nessarly happy? And the other way around assume that you do hard valnteer work or solve puzzle you dont nessrely fill excited you may even fill slicly of suffer, but it give you Satisfaction and in the end happiness so suffer may make you happy if it have meaning and pleasures will not nessarly make you happy. But they come with the actions you do such as share love with the people's you love
